# Android programming - trying to change TextView's text using Java code - error in launch

Tags: java, android, textview, findviewbyid

I'm a beginner with both Java and Android programing. I'm trying to create a `TextView` and then edit its content within Java code.  This is the `TextView` definition:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/NewTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/NewTVS"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And this is the Java code (the needed part, everything else is default):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    TextView mNewTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NewTV);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String newstr = "hello";
    mNewTV.setText(newstr);
}
```

Launching this code causes a problem - the app closing itself. I believe that the problem occurs during the `findViewById` command.

Hopefully I was clear enough despite my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to get reference of `TextView mNewTV`  before setting `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

the order must be like this :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView mNewTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NewTV);
        String newstr = "hello";
        mNewTV.setText(newstr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a very basic mistake:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

it should be come before this

```
TextView mNewTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NewTV);
```

TextView Component is in Layout file. So the hierarchy should follow.

Comment: Tnx a lot! Its working fine now, thank you very much for your help :)